Why do calibration objectives differ between LMM and Hull-White Models?
Hull, J., & White, A. (2001) suggest model volatilities are calculated to minimize the differences between model prices and market prices for benchmark Swaptions ("Specifically we...find the set of volatility parameters that minimizes the sum of the squares of the differences between the model prices and market prices for these options.") On the other hand, for LMM, the objective of calibration is to minimize the differences between the model volatilities and market volatilities. Could anyone explain why these objectives differ? Thank you very much! Reference: Hull, J., & White, A. (2001). The general Hull–White model and supercalibration. Financial Analysts Journal, 57(6), 34-43

It depends on several factors. In some models prices are easier to calculate than volatilities and vice versa. Also the objective function is a bit different due to the different quantities, resulting in slightly different results.
Calibrating prices with certain vega dependent weights multiplied by the least squares terms will be roughly equivalent to calibrating volatilities.

Thank you very much Jesper.
